# How to continuously test for the connection of a Game Controller?

Tags: swift, gamecontroller

**How to continuously test for the connection of a Game Controller?**

Stepping back from code **just for a moment** ...

What do I want to do?

**1)** upon initial start up of app, I want to wait for a **gamepadconnected** Event.

**2)** Once I get this Event by turning **on** my Game Controller,  I immediately change a SKSpriteNode's color and then start looking for:

**a)** button presses on the gamepad **and**

**b)** a *gamepad**dis**connected* Event

**3)** So while I am executing code based on **2(a)**, I receive **2(b)** when I turn **off** my Game Controller. I immediately change the above color to something different, followed by looking for another **gamepadconnected** Event.

*Back-and-forth*.

*Back-and-forth*.

I have tried using Apple's very own `NotificationCenter` Code which works **except for** a significant omission, namely, their Code **never** triggers a **gamepaddisconnected** Event as determined by my placement of multiple `print` statements.

**== start what I have done so far ==**

I **now** call Apple's very own **ObserveForGameControllers()** within my GameViewController's **viewDidLoad()**.

My Nimbus+ Game Controller is set to **off**.

I initially Run my Project, Apple's Code consistently shows "CONNECTED".

Furthermore, Apple states that their two **NotificationCenter.default.addObserver()** **@objc** funcs are continuously called.

Here's Apple's code:

```
func ObserveForGameControllers() {    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(connectControllers),
                name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidConnect,
                object: nil)   // means <Any> Object can send Message
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
                self,
                selector: #selector(disconnectControllers),
                name: NSNotification.Name.GCControllerDidDisconnect,
                object: nil)
            
}   // ObserveForGameControllers
```

Apple's `connectControllers` selector starts the action by waiting for the user to press a Button before doing anything else.

If a Button is pressed then code is executed, e.g., moving a Game Piece in a specific direction.

Now, if for any reason, I disconnect the Game Controller while the Game is running, e.g., via pressing its `Home` Button, I want to call my `stopGame()` to do certain things, like changing colors as specified above. This call to `stopGame()` is placed in my `disconnectControllers` selector.

**But, it's never called!**

I should be able to toggle my Nimbus+ off and on while playing ...

Since Apple states that these two addObserver() **@objc** funcs are cotinuously called. I deliberately have print statements in each **@objc**.

With this toggling is going on, there should be a whole slew of print statements that toggle between "connected" and "dis-connected".

Never happens!!

**== end what I have done so far ==**

Clearly, I am open to use alternatives to Apple's **NotificationCenter** code.

Nevertheless, I really would prefer to stick with the latter.

I just wish I knew how to correctly implement it.

Note: some have blamed the Xcode Simulator because it is obviously not a real device.

Well, I have installed my App on my Apple TV and the same challenges persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED --

1st and foremost, I want to sing the praises of **Keith** at Apple DTS without whom I could never have chased down the cause of my problem. His assistance on this one issue totally pays for my $99.

A **significant** part of the solution rests with the just released update of Xcode to 14.3 **and** tvOS to 16.4

**Now** the expected CONNECTED and DIS-CONNECTED Console messages appear as anticipated.

I've got some more work to do, but at least Apple's

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(..)`

works as Apple advertises.

WHOOPIE!!

Comment: So what's the rest of the solution besides upgrading Xcode and tvOS to the latest version?

Comment: The rest has zero to do with NotificationCenter. It has to do with calling another of my funcs from within a **@obj func**. Specifically accessing one of my vars within the C func.

Comment: My point is that your answer doesn't really provide an answer. It doesn't explain what the actual solution is. You've only stated that you got it solved and that updating some software was a significant (but not all) part of the solution. Please update your answer explaining the complete solution so it can help future readers.

Comment: My OP addressed CONNECTION status, ie, NotificationCenter. I stated this issue was addressed by **major** updates to Xcode and tvOS. These are not **some** updates. End of discussion. Now and forever.

Comment: You stated *"A significant part of the solution rests with..."* - this implies there is still some other part of the solution besides updating the software. Your comments seem to indicate that updating the software is all that is needed. If that's true, your answer should make that clear.